# PHP Curl + HTTPS: Error 502

Tags: php, curl, gateway

I'm trying to get data from secured protocol but I get 502 bad gateway error.
The url's certification is wrong, so I tried to set verifypeer and verifyhost to false and zero.

This is my way:

```
$crl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$result = curl_exec($crl);
```

The url is working fine, nothing special, when I hit in the browser it gives some json data.

I've searched a lot for my problem, but couldn't solved it.

Comment: Do you have the extension `php_openssl` activated in your `php.ini`

Comment: Yes, it is activated

Comment: Will you try with this; $username = 'your_username'; $password = 'your_password'; and change curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");